# How to merge Woocommerce New Account Email with Completed Order Email?

Tags: email, woocommerce, merge, automation

I do not want the customer to receive their New Account Login information email at the time their account is created. I want them to receive their New Account Login when their invoice has been paid. I would like this to be in one email in oder to avoid confusion. There for I would like the New Account Login information included in the Completed Order email. Is there a way to merge the 2? (I am not confident apply my own functions and hooks to piece it together myself)

Comment: it must in itself be possible to achieve this. You can switch off the new account mail at the e-mail settings of woocommerce. You can then transfer the code from that template file to the completed order mail template.

You only need to determine whether this is the first time that a customer has placed an order or not, because this information is otherwise present in each completed order email.

My question: what if a customer creates an account but does not place an order?

Comment: I believe it should be possible too by doing exactly what you suggested but I have not yet had success. As for you Question: My shop is hidden and the shop manager uses the shop to create an order which is sends an invoice via Sliced Invoices, the account is created but there is nothing to log into until they have paid, which is exactly why I don't want the new account email to be sent as soon as the "order" is placed.

Comment: When I did take the contents of the New Account Email Template and add it o the Completed Order Template and tested the credential fields returned blank... I believe you would have to do this and add a specific function to the child theme. I am just not that good.